# Geo conversion with php

Tags: php

I would like to convert a lat/lng string to decimals in php.
An example:

```
N47° 30.5951' = 47+(30.59517/60) = 47.509918333
```

Is there any easy way to do that, regular expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

not sure if E and W belong here, but except that:

```
$regex = "/[EWNS](\d{1,3})°\ (\d{1,3}\.\d{0,10})'/";  
if (preg_match($regex, "N47° 30.5951'", $matches))
{
   $result = $matches[1] + ((float) $matches[2] / 60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do arithmetic in a normal regex replace, but you could write a callback function and use preg_replace_callback.

```
function matches_to_decimal($matches) {
    return $matches[2] + ($matches[3]/60);
}

$inputString = "N47° 30.5951'";
$resultDecimal = preg_replace_callback('/(N|S)(\d+)° (\d+\.?\d*)\'/',
    "matches_to_decimal",
    $inputString);
```

By the way, latitude and longitude are usually written 47°30'35"N, 123°56'12"W, so you could adjust the regex and callback function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/^N(\d+)\° (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\'$/i', "N47° 30.5951'", $bits);
$coord = floatval($bits[1]) + (floatval($bits[2])/60);
```

Forgive my ignorance of lat long, if i'm off the mark.